# Normalize real world GPS coordinates in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, gps, opengl-es-2.0

I am working a project to visualize Geometry like lines, rectangles, cubes with real world coordinates.
The data I work on looks like this:

X                            Y                    Z

320256.49999999988  151844.29689999999  15.24
320256.49999999988  151844.29689999999  15.24
320256.51219999988  151844.29689999999  45.719999999999999
320256.55179999978  151844.2938999999   76.200000000026009
320256.55179999978  151844.2938999999   76.200000000026009
320256.61889999988  151844.2816999999   106.680000000026
320256.70729999989  151844.25119999991  137.15999999928621

These coordinates are in meters in a UTM zone

These are a series of points that needs to be joined by a line. 
I found that we need to have this data normalized for visualizing it in OpenGL.
I tried to normalize the coordinates by using this below formula:
(X - Xmin) / (Xmax - Xmin) .

It doesn't look to work fine.  Can you please suggest how to normalize real world coordinates in order to visualize them in OpenGL ES 2.0 in android

Comment: Maybe you should include a little bit more information about what you're trying to do.  Normal vectors is usually done for lighting, and their use with GPS coordinates eludes me, so perhaps you mean something different.

Comment: Those coordinates still make no sense.  What units are they supposed to be in?

Comment: Are these coordinates in meters in some UTM zone?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "normalizing"? Given the magnitude of the coordinates and the OpenGL ES 2.0 / assumed zoom level constraint, a relative coordinate system will have to be used keep the vertex data representable with single precision floating-point.

Comment: Yes, These coordinates are in meters in a UTM zone.

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing a vector involves dividing it by it's length.  For an 3 value vector with X, Y and Z coordinates, the length is sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2) and the normal would (X / length, Y / length, Z / length).

Comment: My Question was not clear. I edited a bit. can you look at the question once more

Answer (score 0):

you habe to transform spheric wgs84 coordinates to cartesian ones. just multiply by x by cos(latitude)